# Packaging of tetrahedra in $\mathbb Z^3$

Tags: combinatorics, convex-geometry, simplex, polytopes, triangulation

We are allowed to draw tetrahedra whose vertices lie on lattice points in $\mathbb Z^3$, the three-dimensional lattice of unit length. We can only draw tetrahedra of volume $1/6$, and we can only glue them along their faces, to produce a *convex* body $N$. Such $N$ cannot contain lattice points that are not the vertex of some tetrahedron.

Is it possible to produce a body $N$ that contains at least one tetrahedron whose 4 faces are all attached to other tetrahedra?

If that's the case, can one even find a body $N$ that contains at least one tetrahedron whose 4 faces *and* 4 vertices do not lie on the boundary of $N$?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by *"...tetrahedra of minimal area $1/3!$"*? Do you mean the area of the four faces together is at least $\tfrac16$? Because any face has area at least $\tfrac12$.

Comment: @Servaes Sorry, I just meant volume.

Comment: Then similarly, any tetrahedron whose vertices have integral coordinates has volume at least $\tfrac16$.

Comment: @Servaes Sure, that's what we want, but it has to be *exactly* $1/3!$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I originally thought you mean that the tetrahedra should have volume *at least* $\tfrac16$, which is rather void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the six tetrahedra specified by the following lists of vertices:

\begin{align}
(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1);\\
(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,1);\\
(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(0,1,1);\\
(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,1);\\
(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1);\\
(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1).
\end{align}

The idea is we divide the three faces of the unit cube about $(1,1,1)$ each into two triangles separated by the diagonals
$((1,1,0),(1,0,1)),$ $((1,1,0),(0,1,1)),$ and $((1,0,1),(0,1,1)),$
and then we construct a tetrahedron on each of these triangular bases by adding the vertex $(0,0,0).$

These six tetrahedra meet all the requirements for individual tetrahedra, and together they fill the unit cube, which is convex. 
Now reflect this arrangement across any of the faces of the cube. This produces a convex object in which two tetrahedra are each surrounded by four others.

Further, you can construct as large an object as you want by repeated reflection so that all tetrahedra meet the requirements and most of the tetrahedra also are each surrounded by four others. 
In fact, you can fill all of $\mathbb Z^3$ in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to produce a body  that contains at least one tetrahedron whose 4 faces are all attached to other tetrahedra?

Yes, pretty straightforwardly. Consider the 'unit' tetrahedron $\Delta=\{\langle0,0,0\rangle,\langle1,0,0\rangle,\langle0,1,0\rangle,\langle0,0,1\rangle\}$.  Then along all of the faces which the origin we can simply glue reflected copies of this tetrahedron; the only challenge is to glue onto the face $\{\langle1,0,0\rangle,\langle0,1,0\rangle,\langle0,0,1\rangle\}$.  But the tetrahedron with those three vertices and $\langle2,0,0\rangle$ as its fourth vertex also has volume $1/6$, so we can simply glue that one on.

Comment: OP requested that the resulting body be convex, which yours is not.  You can fix it, though, by adding some more reflected tetrahedra.

Comment: @Yly Oops - I was looking at the compound of just the two tetrahedra, not the five-tetrahedron compound.  You're right, though, that reflecting that compound around the three planes through the origin gives a convex body; thanks for the correction!